# Find arc length of $6xy-y^4=3$

Tags: calculus

Find the arc length of $6xy-y^4=3$ from the point $(19/12,2)$ to the point $(14/3,3)$.

On the arc length problems I've had so far, I was given a function $f(t)$ and then found the parameterization of $f(t)$. I don't know how to get going on this problem.

Comment: How about looking at $x$ as a function of $y$ and then integrating along $y$?

Comment: So, use implicit differentiation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can easily express $x$ as a function of $y$:

$$x = \frac{1}{2 y} + \frac16 y^3$$

So compute $dx/dy$:

$$\frac{dx}{dy} = -\frac{1}{2 y^2} + \frac12 y^2$$

and note that the arc length is

$$\int_2^3 dy \sqrt{1+\left ( \frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}$$

It turns out that the integrand reduces to something very simple, and I get $13/4$ for the arc length.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please explain how you got the x as a function of y? And how did you limits of integration end up being 2 to 3? Sorry. I'm just confused on this.

Comment: Getting the function was merely solving the given equation for $x$.  The limits are the $y$-coordinates of the endpoints you specified.

Answer (score 3):

A good point: If $F(x,y)=0$ defines $y$ with respect to $x$ implicitly, then $$y'=\frac{-F_x}{F_y}$$ Now, besides to @Ron's answer, you can use the following formula: $$L=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+y'^2}dx$$

Comment: Nice work. $+1$ for you and Ron!

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy,Ron is a pioneer here. :-)